# Is there a one step build for a GWT application or module in Intellij 11/12?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

Intellij doesn't seem to have a one step way to build a war file from a GWT application. Or am I missing the option somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use maven for project description.

IntelliJ works very good with maven projects. You can use IntelliJ for development and maven for production-builds.

**update**

You can find the documentation here:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/

Steps, to get the stuff running:

- Install maven
- [Create a pom.xml](http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maven-googlewebtoolkit2-plugin/simplesample/)
- define you dependencies
- call `mvn install` and verify you war-file (it will be created in the sub-directory "target"
- call `mvn idea:idea` this will create a Intellj project
  **OR**
- Open Intellij, select "new project from external model -> from maven"

Comment: Can you send me a link to this so I can set it up. As soon as it builds I will select this as the correct answer